# Sampling property of the delta distribution

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, dirac-delta

Let's take for granted the following sampling property of Dirac's delta $\delta_w(x)\triangleq \delta(x-w)$ centered in $w$
\begin{equation*}
\int_S \delta_w(x)\,f(w)\text{ d}w= \begin{cases} 
\quad \hfil f(x)  & \text{ if } S\ni x \\
\quad \hfil 0     & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases} 
\end{equation*}

my question is the following: is it true the following integral simplification?
\begin{equation*}
\int_{S^2} \delta_{w_1}(x)\,f(w_1,w_2)\text{ d}w_1\text{d}w_2= \int_S f(x,w_2)\text{ d}w_2
\end{equation*}

Comment: Yes, indeed that is correct.

Comment: By Fubini's theorem